# Filtering a data frame by values in a column

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I am working with the dataset `LearnBayes`. For those that want to see the actual data:

```
install.packages('LearnBayes')
```

I am trying to filter out rows based on the value in the columns. For example, if the column value is "water", then I want that row. If the column value is "milk", then I don't want it. Ultimately, I am trying to filter out all individuals who's Drink column is "water".

Comment: Try reading `?'['` and then read `?subset`.

Comment: I suggest you read the very good R manuals: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html

Answer (score 286):

The subset command is not necessary.  Just use data frame indexing

```
studentdata[studentdata$Drink == 'water',]
```

Read the warning from `?subset`

> This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.  For
>   programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like
>   ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument
>   ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.

Comment: Thanks @adamleerich. Out of curiosity, what's the reasoning behind the comma?

Comment: The `[ ]` syntax indexes into the 2-dimensional data frame in the normal way that matrices are indexed in math: row and then column, separated by a comma. In this case, we're passing a vector of row indices (`studentData$Drink == 'water'` picks out the rows we're interested in), but since we don't want to restrict which columns we get for those rows (we want all of them), we leave the column part of the index pair blank (so there's nothing after the comma). This is syntactic sugar to avoid having to give a vector of all column indices.

Comment: This does not filter out the data, it merely replaces rows that do not meet the criteria with NA. Another operation is required to remove these rows

Answer (score 92):

Try this:

```
subset(studentdata, Drink=='water')
```

that should do it.

Answer (score 53):

Thought I'd update this with a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)    
filter(studentdata, Drink == "water")
```

Comment: or with pipes `studentdata %>% filter(Drink == "water")`