# Basic R: Subsetting DF by Columns with Logical Vector

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, subset

I have a data frame, `trainSmall`, with six columns.

```
> trainSmall
     chr      pos      end LCR gc.50  type
  1:  22 39491638 39491639   0     0 del_L
  2:  22 29434028 29434029   0     0   ins
  3:  22 28347247 28347248   0     0 del_R
  4:  22 40121931 40121932   0     0   ins
  5:  22 39122351 39122352   0     0 del_L
 ---                                      
768:  22 27869380 27869381   0     0 del_R
769:  22 28823159 28823160   0     0   ins
770:  22 24319557 24319558   0     0 del_R
771:  22 38570330 38570331   0     0 del_L
772:  22 48182139 48182140   0     0 del_L
> is.data.frame(trainSmall)
[1] TRUE
```

I also have a vector, `excl`, with four items.

```
> excl
[1] "chr"  "pos"  "end"  "type"
```

I would like to take all rows of `trainSmall`, but only the columns *not* in `excl`. So I tried

```
> trainSmall[, !colnames(trainSmall) %in% excl]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

But this just gives me another logical vector, not the actual rows from the data frame.

Even doing

```
> trainSmall[, c(F,F,F,T,T,F)]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

doesn't work as I expected.

I'm pretty confused because this seems to be the method advocated in many places (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24191952/2809263)) for subsetting a data frame. What am I doing wrong?

**Response to possible duplicate flag**: None of the solutions there seem to work in this case.

```
> trainSmall[, -which(names(trainSmall) %in% excl)]
[1] -1 -2 -3 -6
> trainSmall[ , !names(trainSmall) %in% excl]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the output of your code, I think your data are in `data.table` format (data table have both data frame and data table as their class). So, this should work:

```
trainSmall[, !excl, with = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go for (note the parentheses):

```
df[, !(colnames(df) %in% excl)]
```

Another fun way would be to make an operator yourself (doing the opposite of `%in%`):

```
excl <- c("chr", "pos", "end", "type")

'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
mask <- colnames(df) %!in% excl
df[,mask]
```

Both will yield

```
   LCR gc.50
1:   0     0
2:   0     0
3:   0     0
4:   0     0
5:   0     0
```

Comment: Interesting--for me, `trainSmall[, !(colnames(trainSmall) %in% excl)]` still leads to `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE`.

Comment: How can I check? `is.data.frame(trainSmall)` is still `TRUE`.

Comment: Looks still like a dataframe to me? `> str(trainSmall)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  772 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ chr  : int  22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 ...
 $ pos  : int  39491638 29434028 28347247 40121931 39122351 30102666 30619293 29877272 36923243 49868710 ...
 $ end  : int  39491639 29434029 28347248 40121932 39122352 30102667 30619294 29877273 36923244 49868711 ...
 $ LCR  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ gc.50: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ type : chr  "del_L" "ins" "del_R" "ins" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> `

Comment: @Randoms: It is a `data.table`, use the approach by @Yannis.

Comment: Defining the custom operator works, but I need to add two periods in front of `mask`: `trainSmall[, ..mask]`