# R delete rows in data frame where nrow of index is smaller than certain value

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe, delete-row

I want to delete certain rows in a data frame when the number of rows with the same index is smaller than a pre-specified value.

```
> fof.6.5[1:15, 1:3]
   draw Fund.ID Firm.ID
1     1    1667     666
2     1    1572     622
3     1    1392     553
4     1     248      80
5     1    3223     332
6     2    2959    1998
7     2    2659    1561
8     2   14233    2517
9     2   10521   12579
10    2    3742    1045
11    3    9093   10121
12    3   15681   21626
13    3   26371   70170
14    4   27633   52720
15    4   13751     656
```

In this example, I want each index to have 5 rows. The third draw (which is my index) has fewer than 5 rows. How can I delete the draws like the third one if they have fewer than 5 rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a data frame by values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381455/filtering-a-data-frame-by-values-in-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `dplyr` (assuming your data is in a data frame called `dt`:

```
dt %>% group_by(draw) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% ungroup()
```

Or you could use `table` or `xtabs`:

```
tab <- xtabs(~ draw, dt)

dt[!dt$draw %in% as.numeric(names(which(tab < 5))), ]
```

Comment: That solution looks very reasonable. However, it does not seem to work: no rows are excluded: > dim(fof.6.5) [1] 9922   32       > fof.6.5 %>% group_by(draw) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% ungroup() > dim(fof.6.5) [1] 9922   32 or > tab <- xtabs(~ draw, fof.6.5)
> new <- fof.6.5[!fof.6.5$draw %in% as.numeric(names(which(tab < 5))), ]
> dim(new)
[1] 9922   32 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not replacing the original data frame with the new one.  `fof.6.5 <- fof.6.5 %>% group_by(draw) %>% filter(n() >= 5) %>% ungroup()` should work

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'draw', `if` the nrows (`.N`) are greater than or equal to 'n' then get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
n <- 5
setDT(df1)[, if(.N >= n) .SD, by = draw]  
#    draw Fund.ID Firm.ID
# 1:    1    1667     666
# 2:    1    1572     622
# 3:    1    1392     553
# 4:    1     248      80
# 5:    1    3223     332
# 6:    2    2959    1998
# 7:    2    2659    1561
# 8:    2   14233    2517
# 9:    2   10521   12579
#10:    2    3742    1045
```

If we want only 'n' number of rows, use the `head`

```
setDT(df1)[, if(.N >= n) head(.SD, n), by = draw]
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below makes that:

```
library(dplyr)
fof.6.5 <- data.frame(draw = rep(1:4, c(5, 5, 3, 2)),
                      Fun.ID = rnorm(15),
                      Firm.ID = rnorm(15))
fof_filter <- fof.6.5 %>% group_by(draw) %>% mutate(freq = n()) %>%
  filter(freq >= 5) %>% select(-freq)
fof_filter
```

- `group_by` join (in someway) profiles with the same value of draw
- `mutate` add a new variable "freq" that give the number of profiles
  per each group of draw and repeats it.
- `filter` selects only those
  profiles with "freq" greater or equals to 5
- `select` delete the "freq"
  column because is not needed anymore