# dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to remove rows corresponding to a particular combination of variables from my data frame.

Here's a dummy data :

```
father<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
mother<- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA) 
children <- c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 2) 
cousins   <- c(NA, 5, 1, 1, 4) 


dataset <- data.frame(father, mother, children, cousins)  
dataset


father  mother  children cousins
1      1       NA      NA
1      1       NA       5
1      1        2       1
1     NA        5       1
1     NA        2       4
```

I want to filter this row :

```
  father  mother  children cousins
    1      1       NA      NA
```

I can do it with :

```
test <- dataset %>% 
filter(father==1 & mother==1) %>%
filter (is.na(children)) %>%
filter (is.na(cousins))
test
```

My question :
I have many columns like grand father, uncle1, uncle2, uncle3 and I want to avoid something like that:

```
  filter (is.na(children)) %>%
  filter (is.na(cousins)) %>%
  filter (is.na(uncle1)) %>%
  filter (is.na(uncle2)) %>%
  filter (is.na(uncle3)) 
  and so on...
```

How can I use dplyr to say filter all the column with na (except  father==1 & mother==1)

Comment: IMO you should convert your data to long format (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381455/filtering-a-data-frame-by-values-in-a-column

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A possible `dplyr`(0.5.0.9004 <= version < 1.0) solution is:

```
# > packageVersion('dplyr')
# [1] ‘0.5.0.9004’

dataset %>%
    filter(!is.na(father), !is.na(mother)) %>%
    filter_at(vars(-father, -mother), all_vars(is.na(.)))
```

Explanation:

- `vars(-father, -mother)`: select all columns except `father` and `mother`.
- `all_vars(is.na(.))`: keep rows where `is.na` is `TRUE` for **all** the selected columns.

note: `any_vars` should be used instead of `all_vars` if rows where `is.na` is `TRUE` for **any** column are to be kept.

---

**Update (2020-11-28)**

As the `_at` functions and `vars` have been superseded by the use of `across` since dplyr 1.0, the following way (or similar) is recommended now:

```
dataset %>%
    filter(across(c(father, mother), ~ !is.na(.x))) %>%
    filter(across(c(-father, -mother), is.na))
```

See more example of `across` and how to rewrite previous code with the new approach here: [Colomn-wise operatons](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html) or type `vignette("colwise")` in R after installing the latest version of `dplyr`.

Answer (score 35):

#### dplyr >= 1.0.4

If you're using dplyr version >= 1.0.4 you really should use `if_any` or `if_all`, which specifically combines the results of the predicate function into a single logical vector making it very useful in `filter`. The syntax is identical to `across`, but these verbs were added to help fill this need: [if_any/if_all](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/).

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
  filter(if_all(-c(father, mother), ~ is.na(.)), if_all(c(father, mother), ~ !is.na(.)))
```

Here I have written out the variable names, but you can use any [tidy selection helper](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) to specify variables (e.g., column ranges by name or location, regular expression matching, substring matching, starts with/ends with, etc.).

**Output**

```
  father mother children cousins
1      1      1       NA      NA
```

Comment: Regarding the anonymous function, can we replace `~ is.na(.)` by `~ is.na(.x)` here ?

Comment: @Julien Yes, that will work. Please see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532119/dplyr-piping-data-difference-between-and-x) regarding this topic.

Comment: This new pair of helper functions are more flexible and should be preferred!

Answer (score 7):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
test <- dataset %>% 
  filter(father == 1 & mother == 1 & rowSums(is.na(.[,3:4])) == 2)
```

Where '2' is the number of columns that should be `NA`.

This gives:

```
> test
  father mother children cousins
1      1      1       NA      NA
```

---

You can apply this logic in base R as well:

```
dataset[dataset$father == 1 & dataset$mother == 1 & rowSums(is.na(dataset[,3:4])) == 2,]
```

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers seems to be an adaptable solution. I think the intention is not to list all the variables and values to filter the data.

One easy way to achieve this is through merging. If you have all the conditions in df_filter then you can do this:

```
df_results = df_filter %>% left_join(df_all)
```

Comment: it is unclear what  "all the conditions in df_filter " means. I would suspect all conditions in dplyr code, but your code example suggests otherwise. Please clarify

Comment: It means all cells meet the condition. Like the example given in the question under "I want to filter this row :".

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R method using two `Reduce` functions and `[` to subset.

```
keepers <- Reduce(function(x, y) x == 1 & y == 1, dataset[, 1:2]) &
           Reduce(function(x, y) is.na(x) & is.na(y), dataset[, 3:4])
keepers
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Each `Reduce` consecutively takes the variables provided and performs a logical check. The two results are connected with an `&`. The second argument to the `Reduce` functions can be adjusted to include whatever variables in the data.frame that you want.

Then use the logical vector to subset

```
dataset[keepers,]
  father mother children cousins
1      1      1       NA      NA
```

Comment: Thank you a lot . I am looking for dplyr

Answer (score 0):

This answer builds on @Feng Jiangs answer using the `dplyr::left_joint()` operation, and is more like a reprex. In addition, it ensures the proper order of columns is restored in case the order of variables in df_filter differs from the order of the variables in the original dataset. Also, the dataset was expanded for a duplicate combination to show these are part of the filtered output (df_out).

```
library(dplyr)

father<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1)
mother<- c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA,1) 
children <- c(NA, NA, 2, 5, 2,NA) 
cousins   <- c(NA, 5, 1, 1, 4,NA)

dataset <- data.frame(father, mother, children, cousins) 
df_filter <- data.frame( father = 1, mother = 1, children = NA, cousins = NA)
                         
test  <- df_filter  %>% 
  left_join(dataset) %>% 
  relocate(colnames(dataset))
```