# Looking for lines that contain a string (eg "aaa") in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (29 columns), I know that in some columns, there are some lines that contain the string `"..."`.
I would like to create a dataframe that contains only the lines where there is in a column (or more) the string `".."`.
I can do it with filter or with select but I do not want to list all my columns by hand.
E.g. :

```
test <- filter(population, pays.Code == ".." | pays.Name == "..")
```

Is there a simple way (preferably without making a loop to stay efficient) to do this?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Can you post your data?  It is easier for people to try to help when the data is available.  You can create code to recreate the data using `dput`

Comment: Are you looking for `".."` or `"..."`? Can you post some data? You might want `filter_all`, `filter_at` or `filter_if`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, I test the response of MR_MPI-BGC. If that does not suit, I'll post the datas. If it works I'll let you know. Thanks Axeman too :-)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using `dplyr` package. Here is what I think is a minimal example, if I understand your question well.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(col1=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc"), col2=c("ddd", "bbb", "aaa"))
df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. == "aaa"))
```

It is what is called scoped filter in `dplyr`. Hope this helped!

Comment: You don't need `library(magrittr)`, pipes are included in `library(dplyr)`

Comment: Thanks MR_MPI-BGC. I try this tomorrow and I'll tell you if it works.

Comment: Hi MR_MPI-BGC,  Your solution works really fine.  Thanks a lot. It's exactly what I need.  See you soon.