# dplyr piping data - difference between `.` and `.x`

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  " " = c(" ", "Part Number 1", "Part Number 2", "Part Number 3"), 
  Julie = c("Measurement 1", 33, 34, 33),
  Julie = c("Measurement 2", 32, 31, 31),
  Joe = c("Measurement 1", 33, 33, 30),
  Joe = c("Measurement 2", 31, 32, 31))

df1 %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  set_names(c("Part", paste(names(.)[2:ncol(.)], .[1, 2:ncol(.)], sep = "-"))) %>%
  `[`(2:nrow(.), ) %>%
  gather("key", "value", contains("Measurement")) %>%
  separate("key", c("person", "measurement"), sep = "-") %>%
  mutate_at("person", ~ stringr::str_replace(.x, "\\..*",""))   # line 14
  # mutate_at("person", ~ stringr::str_replace(., "\\..*",""))  # line 15
```

There's only one thing I want to highlight in the code above, and that's the difference between line #14 and line #15. Notice that the `str_replace()` piped data set for line #14 is `.x` and the piped data set for line #15 is just `.`. I'm used to seeing things in the form of line #15, and it seems the `x` in line #14 is benign.

But the `x` is not benign. If I include it in similar mtcars code (below) I get an error instead of a 'TRUE'. Can you explain this? I've never seen this mysterious `x` syntax before, which hardly means it's not important (or common).

```
identical(mtcars %>% .[1:2, ],
          mtcars %>% .x[1:2, ])
# Error in `[.data.frame`(., .x, 1:2, ) : object '.x' not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.` is the basic unit of transfer for the `magrittr` pipelines (which `dplyr` imports). It contains the value coming from the pipe.

The `.x` value is something that the tidyverse world added. It's used then you have anonymous functions created with the `~` (tilde) syntax. This calls `rlang::as_function` to turn that formula into a function. It's basically a short cut so rather than having to type out `function(x) x+5`, you can just write `~.x+5`. Since functions can have more than one parameter, it can be helpful to use names for that parameter so `.x` refers to the first parameter (and `.y` the second). The `as_function` also allows you to use `.` as an alias for the first parameter. It can do this because the `~` creates a formula and `magrittr` doesn't generally replaces `.` in formulas so the mapper is free to re-interpret the `.`. You can see the function signature here

```
f <- rlang::as_function(~.x+5)
f
# <lambda>
# function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) 
# .x + 5
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "rlang_lambda_function"
```

You can see how both `.` and `.x` are alias for `..1` which is the first parameter passed to the function.

Comment: so when I omit the `x` in line #15 it's just assumed that we're dealing with the first parameter, and that's why the code works with line #14 commented out and line #15 uncommented?

Comment: @JasonHunter. Yes. As mapper understands both `.x` and `.` as being the first parameter. I added an example to perhaps make that more clear.