# Group-by with Fractional Response Model in R

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

I am trying to run a fractional response model to predict test score, using the `frm` package. My code is as follows:

```
frac.test <- sample.test %>% 
  group_by(year, state) %>% 
  do(model = frm(y = sample.test$perc.prof, 
                 x = sample.test[,c("sch.enr", "perc.wh", "perc.bl", "perc.hs", "perc.as", "perc.econ.dis", "perc.ell", "urban.flag", 
                                    "charter.flag", "high", "middle")],
                 linkfrac = "logit"))
```

I want the regression to be grouped by year and state, but currently the results aren't being grouped properly. I can confirm this because if I run the model for a single year and state, I get different predictions. I realize this is similar to the question: [Linear Regression and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169539/linear-regression-and-group-by-in-r) however, it isn't quite the same due to the difference in syntax for frm(). I think because I am calling `y = sample.test$perc.prof` I am losing the grouping, but I am not sure how to fix it. I've also tried with the `nest` and `map` method:

```
frac.test2 <- sample.test %>% 
  nest(-year, -state) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ frm(y = sample.test2$perc.prof, 
                 x = sample.test2[,c("sch.enr", "perc.wh", "perc.bl", "perc.hs", "perc.as", "perc.econ.dis", "perc.ell", "urban.flag", 
                                    "charter.flag", "high", "middle")],
                 linkfrac = "logit")))
```

I am happy to use either method, I just want one that works properly. My data can be found here: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/bf1c215a9c306a7429b314660d31914b/frm_SO_data.csv Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the dataset inside `mutate` using `.x` or `.` not the entire dataset i.e. `sample.test`. use `.` instead of `ample.test` in the 1st method.

```
library(dplyr)
library(frm)
frac.test2 <- sample.test %>% 
  nest(-year, -state) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ frm(y=.x$perc.prof, x=.x[,c("sch.enr", "perc.wh", "perc.bl", "perc.hs", "perc.as", "perc.econ.dis", "perc.ell", "urban.flag", 
                                    "charter.flag", "high", "middle")],
                 linkfrac = "logit")))
```

Comment: Could you explain why it is `.` in some cases and `.x` in other cases?

Comment: @EliGroves `do` uses `.` while `map` uses `.x` or `.`; see `?do` and `?map`. In both cases `.` and `.x` _refer to the subset of rows of .tbl for the given group_. Also, you can see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532119/dplyr-piping-data-difference-between-and-x)