# How to mutate across multiple columns and paste the relevant column name as the cell entry?

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate, across, quasiquotes

I'm trying to mutate across multiple columns to paste in the column name as the entry where the entries are/are not NA.

Using airquality dataset

```
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

I would like to change to this:

```
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5 Ozone Solar.R 14.3   56     5   5
6    28 Solar.R 14.9   66     5   6
```

I've tried

```
airquality %>%
  mutate(across(1:2, paste0(cur_column())))
```

and I get

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(1:2, paste0(cur_column()))`.
Caused by error in `cur_column()`:
! Must only be used inside `across()`
```

I've tried a few other methods of using a function with {{column_name}}, but had no luck.

```
col_tidy_fun <- function(column_name) {
  mutate({column_name} := case_when(
    !is.na({{column_name}}) ~ paste0("{column_name}"),
    TRUE ~ NA
  ))
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thank you, do you know if this would work to select values that are not NA?
Maybe !replace_na() ?

Comment: You can use an `ifelse` to find out records of `NA` and replace them. `airquality %>% mutate(across(1:2, ~ifelse(is.na(.x), cur_column(), .x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::if_else` (or base `ifelse`) to determine which values to replace. Either way you'll need to coerce the columns to characters, as you can't have numeric and character values in the same column:

```
airquality |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~if_else(is.na(.), cur_column(), as.character(.))))
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know if there is a difference between using '.' and '.x' ?
eg
 ~ifelse(is.na(.x), cur_column(), as.character(.x)   VS    if_else(is.na(.), cur_column(), as.character(.)

Comment: My understanding is that either works. `.x` is useful when an anonymous function has multiple inputs and you can use `.x` and `.y`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532119/dplyr-piping-data-difference-between-and-x#:~:text=The.%20is%20the%20basic%20unit%20of%20transfer%20for,value%20is%20something%20that%20the%20tidyverse%20world%20added.