# Using dplyr to filter on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm stumped on something that seems so silly. Is there an elegant dplyr way to filter out only the 2 rows where `year == 2020` and `quarter %in% 1:2`.

I don't want to filter `quarter` for any other year besides 2020.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(measure = rep(letters[1:4], 4),
             year = rep(2017:2020,4)) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(quarter = rep(1:4, 4))

df2 <- filter(df, measure != 2020 & quarter %in% 1:2)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What i want is all but the last two rows:

[image]

Comment: ```df2 <- filter(df, measure != 2020 & quarter %in% 1:2) ``` change 'measure' to 'year' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try negating the entire expression of what you don't want:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !(year == 2020 & quarter %in% 1:2))

   measure year quarter
1        a 2017       1
2        a 2017       2
3        a 2017       3
4        a 2017       4
5        b 2018       1
6        b 2018       2
7        b 2018       3
8        b 2018       4
9        c 2019       1
10       c 2019       2
11       c 2019       3
12       c 2019       4
13       d 2020       3
14       d 2020       4
```

`year == 2020 & quarter %in% 1:2` says to keep rows where the `year` is 2020 AND `quarter` is `1` or `2`. The `!` negates the entire expression so you exclude those rows.

FYI, you can also use `dplyr::between(quarter, 1, 2)`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed!