# Filter data frame using the last_col() function in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have multiple data frames that look this

```
time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5,0.20,0.40,0.50,0.60)

test <- data.frame(time, ID, value)
test

  time ID value
1     1  1  0.00
2     1  2  0.10
3     1  3  0.20
4     1  4  0.40
5     2  1  0.00
6     2  2  0.05
7     2  3  0.05
8     2  4  0.50
9     3  1  0.20
10    3  2  0.40
11    3  3  0.50
12    3  4  0.6
```

I would like to be able to filter the data frame based on the values that are smaller than 0.05 in the last column.
I know I can use easily in baseR `test[,ncol(test)] <0.05`
is there a way that I can incorporate that in dplyr pipe or use that last_col() function
something like: `test %>% filter(.,last_col()<0.05)`

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**dplyr >= 1.0.0**

Using `dplyr::across`:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(across(last_col(), ~ . < 0.05))
```

`across` works here since `last_col` returns a single column. If you're working with more than one column I suggest using `if_any` or `if_all` (depending on your logic). For more information see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908277/6382434).

---

**dplyr < 1.0.0**

Using `filter_at`:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::filter_at(vars(last_col()), ~ . < 0.05)
```

`vars` and `last_col` are also from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: I think the `filter_at` functions are being deprecated. Better get used to `across`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to filter with dplyr and filter

```
library(dplyr)

time <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
value <- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.4,0,0.05,0.05,0.5,0.20,0.40,0.50,0.60)

test <- data.frame(time, ID, value)

test.filter <- test %>%
                  filter(value <= 0.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax figures out the variable name of the last column, and uses the basic filter

```
test %>% filter(!!sym((variable.names(test))[ncol(test)]) < 0.05)
```