# String matching over multiple columns with specific string names

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I am interested in doing string detection over a set of columns. If that string (which in this case is `ZSD`) is found, I want to return the column number/name. If multiple matches are found, I want to return the last column name/number with that string.

#### Input

My input is this:

```
a.zsd                b.zsd   c.zsd   d.zsd
'ZSD'                'ZAD'   NA      'ZAD'
'ZAD'                NA      NA      'ZSD'
NA                   NA      'ZAD'   NA
'Not Achieved ZSD'   NA      'ZAD'   NA
'ZSD'                'ZSD'   NA      'ZSD'
NA                   NA      NA      NA
```

#### Output

My required output is a new column `zsd.level`:

```
a.zsd                b.zsd   c.zsd   d.zsd zsd.level
'ZSD'                'ZAD'   NA      'ZAD'    a
'ZAD'                NA      NA      'ZSD'    d
NA                   NA      'ZAD'   NA       NA
'Not Achieved ZSD'   NA      'ZAD'   NA       a
'ZSD'                'ZSD'   NA      'ZSD'    d
NA                   NA      NA      NA       NA
```

#### Info:

My data frame has over a hundred columns. I am interested in ONLY some of the columns having a name that ends at a string `.zsd`. These columns can either have `NA` or one of the following string values `ZAD`, `ZSD`, `Not Achieved ZSD`.

I am just interested in detecting the presence of the string `ZSD`. If not found in any of the columns, it should return NA in the output column (`zsd.level`). If the string is found in multiple columns, I want to return the last column name/number that contains the string.

My question is similar to this post but not exactly the same [dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns)

#### dput

```
dput(df)

structure(list(a.zsd = c("ZSD", "ZAD", NA, "Not Achieved ZSD", "ZSD", NA), 
               b.zsd = c("ZAD", NA, NA, NA, "ZSD", NA), 
               c.zsd = c(NA, NA, "ZAD", "ZAD", NA, NA), 
               d.zsd = c("ZAD", "ZSD", NA, NA, "ZSD", NA)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

#### Partial Solution

To select those columns with names ending in `.zsd`, I can do

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  select(ends_with(".zsd"))
```

To select or filter rows with the string `ZSD`, I can do

```
str_detect(., "ZSD"))
```

But how can I put multiple conditions together? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if `ZSD` is multiple columns like in row 5

Comment: "If multiple matches are found, I want to return the last column with that string."

Comment: Sorry, it's a string. I should update and clarify that it's just in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%  
  mutate(across(contains("zsd"), ~case_when(str_detect(., "ZSD") ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(zsd_level, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate(zsd_level = str_remove_all(zsd_level, ".zsd"),
         zsd_level = str_sub(zsd_level, -1))
```

output:

```
 a.zsd b.zsd c.zsd d.zsd zsd_level
1              ZSD   ZAD  <NA>   ZAD         a
2              ZAD  <NA>  <NA>   ZSD         d
3             <NA>  <NA>   ZAD  <NA>          
4 Not Achieved ZSD  <NA>   ZAD  <NA>         a
5              ZSD   ZSD  <NA>   ZSD         d
6             <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: See my update. Now it should be adequate!

Comment: That's great, it's mostly working. I can improve on including the NA value when the string is missing. I will now check on my original data. Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please have a look at the following post
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609589/string-matching-and-value-comparison-over-multiple-columns>

Answer (score 2):

Another option, but a little bit more complicated than dear TarJae's:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rn) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(value, "ZSD")) %>% 
  slice_tail() %>% 
  summarise(name = str_remove(name, ".zsd")) %>% 
  right_join(df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()), by = "rn") %>%
  arrange(rn) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(ends_with("zsd"), zsd.level = name)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  a.zsd            b.zsd c.zsd d.zsd zsd.level
  <chr>            <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    
1 ZSD              ZAD   NA    ZAD   a        
2 ZAD              NA    NA    ZSD   d        
3 NA               NA    ZAD   NA    NA       
4 Not Achieved ZSD NA    ZAD   NA    a        
5 ZSD              ZSD   NA    ZSD   d        
6 NA               NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Nice solution. I like it.

Comment: @Martin Gal, Could you please have a look at the following post
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609589/string-matching-and-value-comparison-over-multiple-columns>

Comment: Thank you for the solution, however, it does not work on the original data.