# String matching over multiple columns with specific strings and value comparisons in associated names

Tags: r, string, comparison, multiple-columns

I am interested in doing string detection and value comparison across a range of columns. If the string (which in this case is `ZSD`) is found in columns, then their corresponding values from another column need to be compared.

#### Input

My input is as below:

```
a.zsd                 a.test b.zsd b.test c.zsd c.test d.zsd d.test
'ZSD'                 0.0   'ZAD'  1.0    NA    0.5   'ZAD'    1.0
'ZAD'                 1.0    NA    0.0    NA    0.5   'ZSD'    0.0
NA                    0.5    NA    0.5   'ZAD'  0.5    NA      0.5
'Not Achieved ZSD'    0.0    NA    0.5   'ZAD'  0.5    NA      0.5
'ZSD'                 1.0   'ZSD'  0.5    NA    0.5   'ZSD'    0.0
NA                    0.0    NA    0.0    NA    0.5    NA      0.0
NA                    1.0   'ZSD'  0.0   'ZSD'  0.5   'ZSD'    1.0
```

#### Output

In my output, I want two additional columns `smallest.test` and `zsd.level`:

```
a.zsd                 a.test b.zsd b.test c.zsd c.test d.zsd d.test smallest.test zsd.level
'ZSD'                 0.0   'ZAD'  1.0    NA    0.5   'ZAD'    1.0  0.0           a
'ZAD'                 1.0    NA    0.0    NA    0.5   'ZSD'    0.0  0.0           d
NA                    0.5    NA    0.5   'ZAD'  0.5    NA      0.5  0.0           NA        
'Not Achieved ZSD'    0.0    NA    0.5   'ZAD'  0.5    NA      0.5  0.0           a
'ZSD'                 1.0   'ZSD'  0.5    NA    0.5   'ZSD'    0.0  0.0           d
NA                    0.0    NA    0.0    NA    0.5    NA      0.0  0.0           NA
NA                    1.0   'ZSD'  0.0   'ZSD'  0.5   'ZSD'    1.0  0.0           b
```

#### Info:

My data frame has over a hundred columns. I am interested in ONLY some of the columns having a name that ends at a string `.zsd`. These columns can either have `NA` or one of the following string values `ZAD`, `ZSD`, `Not Achieved ZSD`. Each column with the `.zsd` string name, has an associated `.test` column.

#### Requirements

I want two new columns in the output `smallest.test` and `zsd.level`. The requirements are as below:

1. Iterate through the column names ending with the string `.zsd`
2. Across those columns detect the string `ZSD`
3. If the `ZSD` string is found in only one of the columns, return the names of that column in the output column `zsd.level` and also return the corresponding value from the column name ending at `.test` to be returned to the output column `smallest.test`.
4. If none of the columns contains the string `ZSD`, return NA in the output column `zsd.level` and return 0.0 in the corresponding output column `smallest.test`.
5. If more than one columns contain the string `ZSD`, pick the column with the least value of the corresponding `.test` column and return in the output.
6. If more than one columns contain the string `ZSD`, and they all have the same value of the corresponding `.test` column, then pick the last column name for the output and the corresponding value of the `.test` for the output.

#### dput()

```
    dput(df)
    structure(list(a.zsd = c("ZSD", "ZAD", NA, "Not Achieved ZSD", "ZSD", NA, NA), 
                   a.test = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                   b.zsd = c("ZAD", NA, NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
                   b.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), 
                   c.zsd = c(NA, NA, "ZAD", "ZAD", NA, NA, "ZSD"), 
                   c.test = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
                   d.zsd = c("ZAD", "ZSD", NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
                   d.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1)), 
                   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

#### Partial solution

Based on the following post: [String matching over multiple columns with specific string names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69609057/string-matching-over-multiple-columns-with-specific-string-names/69609103#69609103), this code can iterate and select the `.zsd` columns and return the highest column name in the output. But it does not take into account the corresponding values of the `.test` field. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%  
  mutate(across(contains("zsd"), ~case_when(str_detect(., "ZSD") ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(zsd_level, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  mutate(zsd_level = str_remove_all(zsd_level, ".zsd"),
         zsd_level = str_sub(zsd_level, -1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `base` solution involving `which.min` that presumes the corresponding '.test' and '.zsd' columns are adjacent.

The first block of code can be used for this purpose, but if a given row has ties in the minima, it will give the first instance. Further below is a function that can be used to select either the first or last instance of the minima.

```
# sample data
df <- structure(list(a.zsd = c("ZSD", "ZAD", NA, "Not Achieved ZSD", "ZSD", NA, NA), 
               a.test = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
               b.zsd = c("ZAD", NA, NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
               b.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0), 
               c.zsd = c(NA, NA, "ZAD", "ZAD", NA, NA, "ZSD"), 
               c.test = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
               d.zsd = c("ZAD", "ZSD", NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
               d.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


# select .zsd columns
zsd_cols <- grep(".zsd", names(df), value = TRUE)
zsd_df <- df[, zsd_cols]

# select .test columns
test_cols <- gsub("zsd", "test",zsd_cols)
test_df <- df[, test_cols]

# convert "Not Achieved ZSD" to "ZSD"
zsd_df[zsd_df == "Not Achieved ZSD" ] <- "ZSD"

# assign NA to non "ZSD" cells
zsd_df[zsd_df != "ZSD"] <- NA

# assign 999 test_df values whose corresponding zsd_df is NA
test_df[is.na(zsd_df)] <- 999

# return cols which hold minimum
nams <- names(test_df)[apply(test_df, 1 ,which.min)]

# scrub .test suffix
nams <- gsub(".test", "", nams)

# return mins
mins <- apply(test_df, 1 ,min)

# assign values less than 999 as smallest test, or zero
df$smallest.test <- ifelse(mins < 999, mins, 0)

# assign name if corresponding min less than 999 or NA
df$zsd_level <- ifelse(mins < 999, nams, NA)

> df
             a.zsd a.test b.zsd b.test c.zsd c.test d.zsd d.test smallest.test zsd_level
1              ZSD    0.0   ZAD    1.0  <NA>    0.5   ZAD    1.0             0         a
2              ZAD    1.0  <NA>    0.0  <NA>    0.5   ZSD    0.0             0         d
3             <NA>    0.5  <NA>    0.5   ZAD    0.5  <NA>    0.5             0      <NA>
4 Not Achieved ZSD    0.0  <NA>    0.5   ZAD    0.5  <NA>    0.5             0         a
5              ZSD    1.0   ZSD    0.5  <NA>    0.5   ZSD    0.0             0         d
6             <NA>    0.0  <NA>    0.0  <NA>    0.5  <NA>    0.0             0      <NA>
7             <NA>    1.0   ZSD    0.0   ZSD    0.5   ZSD    1.0             0         b
```

**EDIT**

Same idea, but a function that can obtain the first or last minimum when ties are present in a row:

```
# adjusted sample data
df <- data.frame(a.zsd = c("ZSD", "ZAD", NA, 
                        "Not Achieved ZSD", "ZSD", NA, NA), 
                 a.test = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0, 1, 0, 1), 
                 b.zsd = c("ZAD", NA, NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
                 b.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0, 0), # adjusted 
                 c.zsd = c(NA, NA, "ZAD", "ZAD", NA, NA, "ZSD"), 
                 c.test = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
                 d.zsd = c("ZAD", "ZSD", NA, NA, "ZSD", NA, "ZSD"), 
                 d.test = c(1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 1))


appendMin <- function(df, last_min = TRUE){
  
  # select .zsd columns
  zsd_cols <- grep(".zsd", names(df), value = TRUE)
  zsd_df <- df[, zsd_cols]
  if(last_min) { zsd_df <- rev(zsd_df) } # for last min
  
  # select .test columns
  test_cols <- gsub("zsd", "test",zsd_cols)
  test_df <- df[, test_cols]
  if(last_min) { test_df <- rev(test_df) } # for last min
  
  # convert "Not Achieved ZSD" to "ZSD"
  zsd_df[zsd_df == "Not Achieved ZSD" ] <- "ZSD"
  
  # assign NA to non "ZSD" cells
  zsd_df[zsd_df != "ZSD" ] <- NA
  
  # assign 999 test_df values whose corresponding zsd_df is NA
  test_df[is.na(zsd_df)] <- 999
  
  # return cols which hold the first minimum 
  nams <- names(test_df)[apply(test_df, 1 ,which.min)]
  
  # scrub .test suffix
  nams <- gsub(".test", "", nams)
  # return mins
  mins <- apply(test_df, 1 ,min)
  
  # assign values less than 999 as smallest test, or zero
  df$smallest.test <- ifelse(mins < 999, mins, 0)
  
  # assign name if corresponding min less than 999 or NA
  df$zsd_level <- ifelse(mins < 999, nams, NA)
  
  return(df)
  
}


ties_first <- appendMin(df, last_min = FALSE)
ties_last <- appendMin(df, last_min = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much xillian
I like your solution. It mostly works except in row 4. Although the string is 'Not Achieved ZSD', it should still consider it because of the presence of the string ZSD.

Comment: I see, I'll update the answer.

Comment: I tried the following, but it did not work...:

```zsd_df[(is.na(zsd_df)) || (zsd_df == "ZAD")] <- NA```

Comment: I just noticed that in the code, ```which.min``` picks the first minimum entry. @xilliam, is it possible that we modify the code so that it picks the last minimum entry?

Comment: I edited to include a function that can return either the first or last minimum in cases of ties.

Comment: Greatly appreciate it @Xilliam