# Filtering by multiple columns at once in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is some sample data

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- matrix(runif(20), ncol = 4) 
colnames(data) <- c("mt100", "cp001", "cp002", "cp003")
data <- as_tibble(data)
```

The real data set has many more columns but it stands that there are many columns that all start with "cp". In `dplyr` I can select all these columns

```
data %>%
  select(starts_with("cp"))
```

Is there a way in which I can use the `starts_with` (or similar function) to filter by multiple columns without having to explicitly write them all? I'm thinking something like this

```
data %>%
  filter(starts_with("cp") > 0.2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66908277/6619692

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr filter with condition on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938863/dplyr-filter-with-condition-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We could use `if_all` or `if_any` as Anil is pointing in his comments: For your code this would be:

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

**if_any() and if_all()**

"across() is very useful within summarise() and mutate(), but it’s hard to use it with filter() because it is not clear how the results would be combined into one logical vector. So to fill the gap, we’re introducing two new functions if_all() and if_any()."

**if_all**

```
data %>% 
  filter(if_all(starts_with("cp"), ~ . > 0.2))
```

```
  mt100 cp001 cp002 cp003
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.688 0.402 0.467 0.646
2 0.663 0.757 0.728 0.335
3 0.472 0.533 0.717 0.638
```

**if_any:**

```
data %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("cp"), ~ . > 0.2))
```

```
  mt100 cp001   cp002 cp003
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.554 0.970 0.874   0.187
2 0.688 0.402 0.467   0.646
3 0.658 0.850 0.00813 0.542
4 0.663 0.757 0.728   0.335
5 0.472 0.533 0.717   0.638
```

Comment: I believe op needs `if_all` which will give similar results as `across`

Comment: Thank you very much Onyambu. I have updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks very much! I'm new(ish) to `dplyr` (I used to do everything manually) and it's great that there's a function for almost everything I need to do!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `dplyr::across()` along with a purrr-style anonymous function:

```
data %>%
  filter(across(starts_with("cp"), ~ . > .2))
# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   mt100 cp001 cp002 cp003
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.628 0.604 0.802 0.501
# 2 0.744 0.283 0.702 0.493
# 3 0.279 0.372 0.975 0.751
```

(Note that without a `set.seed()`, our results will differ due to the RNG.)

Comment: This will require that any resulting rows satisfy that condition in ALL the columns right?

Comment: Correct. But don't trust me - try it out on a little sample data!