# grepl() to filter using two columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, grepl

I am trying to filter in R with grepl() if "Y" is present in a row in either column 1 and/or column 2. I tried this code and it did not work.

```
filter(grepl("Y", column1|column2))
```

Comment: Try `filter(grepl("Y", column1) | grepl("Y", column2))`

Comment: How about `filter(grepl (“Y”, paste(column1,column2)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if_any`, along with a selector for the columns. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(column1 = c("Y", "N", "N"), 
                  column2 = c("N", "Y", "N"))

df1 %>% 
  filter(if_any(all_of(c("column1", "column2")), ~grepl("Y", .)))
```

or

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(if_any(starts_with("column"), ~grepl("Y", .)))
```

Result in both cases:

```
  column1 column2
1       Y       N
2       N       Y
```

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this. See also here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884982/filtering-by-multiple-columns-at-once-in-dplyr/70885695#70885695> and try out `df1 %>% 
  filter(across(starts_with("column"), ~grepl("Y", .)))` -> It won't work as expected or desired!