# Filter a dataframe by values in a column of type list

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm aware there are a lot of answered similar questions. For example:
[Filter data.frame rows by a logical condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381455/filtering-a-data-frame-by-values-in-a-column)
. The problem is these answers don't work when the type of the column is a list.

In fact, I'm using the [Yelp businesses dataset](https://www.yelp.com/dataset) that I've loaded using the library [jsonlite](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/jsonlite/versions/1.5/topics/stream_in%2C%20stream_out) (flattening the result). One of the columns, the categories of the business, is a list of strings.

```
> typeof(business_df["categories"])
[1] "list"
> business_df[1:3, "categories"]
[[1]]
[1] "Shopping"         "Shopping Centers"

[[2]]
[1] "Food"               "Soul Food"          "Convenience Stores" "Restaurants"       

[[3]]
[1] "Food"         "Coffee & Tea"
```

For now, I have this horrible solution:

```
filterByCategory <- function(category) {
  filtered_df <- cbind(businesses_df)
  if (category != "All") {
    filtered_df[, "belongs"] <-
      apply(filtered_df["categories"], 1, function(x)
        is.element(category, x[[1]]))
    filtered_df <<- subset(filtered_df, belongs)
  }
}
```

As you can see, I need to access the column with the `[[1]]` syntax. This is why I think none of these solutions actually work:

```
# All rows returned 
business_df[category %in% business_df$categories]
subset(business_df, category %in% business_df$categories)
# No rows returned
business_df %>% filter(category %in% categories)
```

Comment: So, your list has as its elements character vectors and you want to extract elements of all those vectors?

Comment: Can you provide a short snippet of either the JSON or the R object you need to filter. The Yelp dataset is quite large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to filter a data frame where a list column contains a specific value.

`categories` is a list of vectors. `map_lgl` will map each element (vector) of the list into a `logical`.

```
library('tidyverse')

df <- tribble(
  ~rownum, ~categories,
        1, c('a', 'b'),
        2, c('c', 'd'),
        3, c('d', 'e')
)

# All rows containing the 'd' category
df %>%
  filter(map_lgl(categories, ~'d' %in% .)) %>%
  str
#> Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ rownum    : num  2 3
#>  $ categories:List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr  "c" "d"
#>   ..$ : chr  "d" "e"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I also tried using ```subset```.