# How to add row to other matrix

Tags: r

I have following panel data:

```
firmid date return
1        1     1
1        2     1
1        3     1
2        2     2
2        3     2
3        1     2
3        3     2
```

I want to transform this long format to wide but only for date 1 to look like this

```
firmid return in date=1
 1        1
 3        2
```

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Isn't the result you posted still in long format? I believe you can get something that looks like your desired result if you do: `mat[mat$date == 1,]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a data frame by values in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381455/filtering-a-data-frame-by-values-in-a-column)

Comment: Similar to @Mike H, you could also use `subset(mat, date == 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "firmid date return
1        1     1
1        2     1
1        3     1
2        2     2
2        3     2
3        1     2
3        3     2")
```

Base R solution:

```
df <- df[df$date == 1, ]
df$date <- NULL
df
     firmid return
1      1      1
6      3      2
```

`data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df <- df[date == 1, ]
df[, date := NULL]

     firmid return
1:      1      1
2:      3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` to achieve it too:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>% 
    filter(date == 1) %>%
    select(-date)

#  firmid return
#1      1      1
#2      3      2
```

---

Answer (score 0):

A different `dplyr` solution that allows you to have multiple values of return within firmid:

```
df %>%
  filter(date == 1) %>%
  group_by(firmid, return) %>%
  summarise()
```