# Filtering a data frame by values in a column using wildcards

Tags: r, filter, wildcard

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381455/filtering-a-data-frame-by-values-in-a-column) I was made aware you can filter data out of a data frame based on a value using data frame indexing.

e.g.:

```
studentdata[studentdata$Drink == 'water',]
```

How would I perform the same task but filter for e.g. water_cold and water_hot?

This does not work

```
studentdata[studentdata$Drink == 'water*',]
```

Comment: Use `grepl` i.e. `studentdata[grepl("water.*", studentdata$Drink),]`

Comment: Or `library(tidyverse); dplyr::filter(studentdata, str_detect(Drink, "water_*"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_detect` from `stringr` as such:

```
library(tidyr) 

studentdata %>% 
    filter(str_detect(Drink, "water"))
```